# Streak of the user consecutively login in the app(Android)

Tags: java, android

I want to check how many days the user consecutively login into the app and store it to a sync counter variable(1 day mean sync=1) and increment the sync as the user login consecutively and as the user miss a day we set the sync counter to 0, how can I implement this functionality and calculate the sync variable.

Comment: Unless you sync with server's current time, it'll be prone to exploiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save date information in [shared preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) and make use of it when the user logs in again. I commented few methods, uncomment and use them in the android environment.

```
class ConsecutiveDayChecker {

    /**
     * Call this method when user login
     */
    public void onUserLogin() {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        Date date = new Date();
        String today = dateFormat.format(date);
        String lastLoginDay = getLastLoginDate();

        String yesterday = getYesterdayDate(dateFormat, date);

        if (lastLoginDay == null) {
            // user logged in for the first time
            updateLastLoginDate(today);
            incrementDays();
        } else {
            if (lastLoginDay.equals(today)) {
                // User logged in the same day , do nothing
            } else if (lastLoginDay.equals(yesterday)) {
                // User logged in consecutive days , add 1
                updateLastLoginDate(today);
                incrementDays();
            } else {
                // It's been more than a day user logged in, reset the counter to 1
                updateLastLoginDate(today);
                resetDays();
            }
        }
    }

    private String getYesterdayDate(DateFormat simpleDateFormat, Date date) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
        return simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
    }

    /**
     * Update last login date into the storage
     * @param date
     */
    private void updateLastLoginDate(String date) {
        // SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        // editor.putString("last_login_day", date);
        // editor.apply();
    }

    /**
     * Get last login date 
     * @return
     */
    private String getLastLoginDate() {
        // String lastLogin = null;
        // SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // lastLogin = sharedPref.getString("last_login_day", null);
        // return lastLogin;
    }

    private int getConsecutiveDays() {
        // int days = 0;
        // SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // days = sharedPref.getInt("num_consecutive_days", 0);
        // return days;
    }

    private void incrementDays() {
        // int days = getConsecutiveDays() + 1;
        // SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        // editor.putInt("num_consecutive_days", days);
        // editor.apply();
    }

    private void resetDays() {
        // int days = 1;
        // SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        // editor.putInt("num_consecutive_days", days);
        // editor.apply();
    }

    public int getStreak() {
        return getConsecutiveDays();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to store two bits of information:

- sync, being the number of days of consecutive sync
- last_sync, being the date of the previous sync

Then, when connecting, you have the logic:

- if last_sync was today, don't do anything
- if last_sync was yesterday, increment the sync counter and store the date into the last_sync
- if last_sync is older than yesterday or not present, reset sync to 0 and store the date into the last_sync

Comment: Can you please share the code

Comment: This is not a free consultancy website. As you are a student, it feels like you are trying to get people to do your homework. I am willing to invest time to assist you and help you learn but not work for free.